# undefined reference to extern variable

Tags: c++, extern

I'm trying to use an extern file pointer declared in a header file in two different .cpp files.  The following code is a reduced version of my project, but the logic is the same:

file2.h:

```
extern FILE* output;
void print_stuff();
```

file1.cpp:

```
#include "file2.h"
int main() {
    output = fopen("hello.txt", "w");
    print_stuff();
}
```

file2.cpp

```
void print_stuff() {
    fprintf(output, "hello\n");
}
```

however, I'm getting undefined reference errors to the output filepointer in both cpp files.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define it in `file2.cpp`, like `FILE* output;`.

Comment: thanks, that worked!

Comment: This question should not have been tagged C. Only use the C tag for code that is intended to be compiled with a C (not C++) compiler.

Comment: removed the tag